# Wordpress Help: How to use custom blog page for blog category

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

My blog page is a custom tempate `page-blog.php`. I want to use the same template for blog category as well `/blog/category/architectural/`. Currently it is pointing to the homepage of the website that is the `index.php`

I also tried this Rewrite plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite/ to change the rules for `blog/category`.

Any idea on how to tackle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create the file category-architectural.php with this content `<?php include "page-blog.php"; ?>`

Comment: Well, I cannot create pages for each category. Categories can grow. Is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: So you can create de category.php with same content! See more about Wordpress Template Hierarchy https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: And what about the category pages for custom post type known as "Projects"?

Comment: archive-project.php. See the link, dude.